# How do I get the current host in Cucumber javascript tests?

Tags: javascript, cucumber

I am trying to write a Javascript test that needs to know the host of the test server before the browser launcher has opened a browser. How can I find out this information from my Cucumber steps?

Comment: How you are running the tests?. Do you have a rails application ?